# Possible to simulate select using setSelection?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a project where I am using the vis.js timeline module as a type of image carousel where I have a start and an end time, plot the events on the timeline, and cycle through them automatically and show the image attached to each event in another container.

I already have this working and use something similar to the following to accomplish this, except one part:

```
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data);

timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
// do some cool stuff
}

var i = 0;

(function timelapseEvents(i) {

    setTimeout(function(){

        timeline.setSelection(data[i], {focus: true, animation:true});

        if (i < data.length - 1)  { 
        timelapseEvents(i+1); 
        }

    }, 2000);

})(i)
```

The `timeline.setSelection()` part above works, the timeline event is selected and focused on. However, the "select" event is **NOT** triggered. This is verified as working as expected in the documentation (under [Events](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Events) > timeline.select) where it says: `Not fired when the method timeline.setSelection() is executed.`

So my question is, does anyone know how to use the `timeline.setSelection()` method and actually trigger the `select` event? Seems unintuitive to me to invoke the `timeline.setSelection()`method and not actually trigger the select event.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few hours on this and came up short. I ended up just taking the code I had in my `timeline.on('select', function (properties) {` block and turning it into a function and calling it after the `timeline.setSelection()` call.

Basically, I didn't fix the issue but worked around it. Will keep an eye on this in case anyone actually is able to figure out how to add the `select()` event to the `setSelection()` method.